# To implement like feature by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

My site is almost finished. However,one last thing being a problem. I want to implement a ajax liking feature.

When the user will click on the button, the ajax should fire off and increment the value in the database and as well as on the display.

My problem is everything is working fine except the ajax part, I have barely used ajax and not understanding how to implement it. Ajax should match the URL with the routing of node.js and display the result. Here is the relevant code.

Here is my handlebars template:

```
 <div class="row">

    {{#each event}} {{#is this.event ../eventName }}

    <div class="col s12 m3 13 al">
        <div class="card ">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="/Small/{{this.imageId}}.JPG">
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">

                <a id="like_feature" href="/{{this.imageId}}/love" class="like">Love
                    <i class="material-icons fav">favorite</i>
                </a>


                <span class="rank">Rank: xxx
                    <i class="material-icons eq">equalizer</i>
                </span>
                {{!-- {{this.imageId}} --}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <span class="number_of_likes">Number of likes: {{this.vote}}</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    {{/is}} {{/each}}


</div>
```

This is my route which is handling the like feature

```
app.get('/:id/love', (req, res) => {
console.log("Hitting");
var image_Id = req.params.id;
var query = {
    "imageId": image_Id
}
var update = {
    $inc: {
        vote: 1
    }
}

likeImformation.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, function (err, voted) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(404)
    } else {
        console.log(voted);
        res.send("loved");
    }
});})
```

And this is what ajax I am able to build till now by reading tutorials, i am not understanding how to move after this

```
$(function(){
$('#like_feature').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'love',
        type:'GET',
        success:function(){
            console.log("it is been liked");
        },
        error: function () {
          console.log("Not been liked");
        }
    })
})
```

})

Comment: Assuming the ajax part works, all that is left to do is update your UI from within the success function.  However to me it looks like the ajax URL should be `/some ID goes here/love` to match the controller.  Use the developer tools in your browser (hit F12, network tab) to follow an ajax request, examine where it gets sent to and what error message or data gets sent back to the browser.  Once it's working (and you see "it has been liked" in the console), add code to update the UI in the success function.

Comment: i guess i should be able to easily implement the UI updation. And yes you are right about `/some ID goes here/love`. I am trying to make it dynamic.

Comment: Finally able to solve it, will post the answer tomorrow though

Answer (score 0):

```
function callAjax() {
    // the XMLHttpRequest returns the ajax object that has several cool methods, so you store it in the request variable
    // @data contains the $GET[liked],$GET[whatever] since we are using GET method, if you're using PHP as a server side language
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = 'place_here_the_url_only',
        data = 'liked=1&whatever=dataYouWantToSendToServerFromBrowser',
        token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

    // when the server is done and it came back with the data you can handle it here
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // do whatever you want!
            console.log("The request and response was successful!");
       }
    };

    // method get, your giving it the URL, true means asynchronous
    request.open('GET', url + "?" + data, true);
    // set the headers so that the server knows who is he talking to, I'm using laravel 5.5
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    // Token needed
    request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
    // then you send the data and wait for the server to return the response
    request.send();
}
```

This is the vanilla javascript version.
However, now on the server take the $_GET['liked'], after validation and checking if it's a 1 update the database.